# Can other players donate things to my museum, or can I prevent them from doing so?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I want to complete all the collections in my museum on my own.  Can other players donate to my museum?  Is there any way I can have the museum only accept my donations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Players cannot donate to a museum that is not part of their own town. As such, the only way that someone else aside from your town mayor can donate to your museum is if you create another resident who lives in your town and donate that way.

No one can donate to your museum while they're visiting you because it's not their own town, so you don't have to worry about trying to "block" them from doing so.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was worried because it shows the name of who donated each item.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yeah, that's just so you can keep track if you have more than one resident in your town.

Comment: @user9983 "I was worried because it shows the name of who donated each item" it is kind of funny because nobody really checks who donated it and let's say 3 to 5 years down the road, nobody really even start the game up any more, so who really would care? But I can see if you want to donate yourself for the sake of completing the task yourself -- on your own and not by any random people who visit you (such as visitors who come up to sell vegetable and randomly go into your museum and donate)